# What vegan or animal rights events have spread internationally?

Tags: veganism, outreach, history, animal-rights

In the past few years the environmentalism movement has seen large events like New York’s “People’s Climate March” turn into international events where many cities rallied around the same message. These international events often share graphics or messaging, but are not necessarily organized by a central body.

Are there any similar examples from the vegan/animal rights movement where a particular cause or message has generated recognized events in multiple cities internationally, either recently or historically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[National Animal Rights Day](http://thenard.org/)** (since 2011)

> Established by the non-profit Our Planet. Theirs Too. in 2011, The National Animal Rights Day (NARD) is an annual day observed in multiple countries around the world on the first Sunday in June, for the purpose of giving a voice to all animals and raising awareness for their rights, until all animals are free from enslavement and their rights are established and protected by law.

**[March To Close Down All Slaughterhouses](https://stopabattoirs.org/)** (since 2012)

The first *Marche pour la fermeture des abattoirs* (march for the closing of slaughterhouses) [gathered 400 people](https://stopabattoirs.org/2012-march-for-the-closure-of-the-slaughterhouses) in Paris, France. Since then the event has gone international with events being organized in 15 different countries.

**[The Save Movement](http://thesavemovement.org/)** (since 2012)

> The Save Movement is a worldwide network of groups **bearing witness** to farmed animals, advocating veganism, & promoting love-based grassroots activism.

I believe this movement started with [Toronto Pig Save](https://www.thestar.com/news/gta/2012/05/09/porter_toronto_pig_save_activists_protest_slaughter_weekly_at_quality_meat_packers_abattoir.html).

**[Empty The Tanks](http://emptythetanks.org/events/)** (since 2013)

> Marine entertainment parks have no place in our world anymore. These are incredibly social, intelligent beings that are being exploited to make money. It is animal slavery, and it needs to be brought to the general public’s attention.

**Roaring Silence** (since 2016)

Roaring Silence is a peaceful demonstration [first shown in Tel Aviv](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwojZMz7C7Q), Israel in 2016. The first event was organized by the Israeli Animal Liberation Front and similar events have been organized in Canada (Edmonton and Vancouver).